# How function exist after component has been unmounted

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My Doubt is related to using timer in react component, as per my understanding **once component unmount** its all properties/methods will not exist after that.

As per [DOC](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillunmount):

> componentWillUnmount() is invoked immediately before a component is
>   unmounted and destroyed. **Perform any necessary cleanup in this method,
>   such as invalidating timers,** canceling network requests, or cleaning
>   up any DOM elements that were created in componentDidMount.

Check this snippet:

```js
class Clock extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {count: 1};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.timerID = setInterval(
      () => this.tick(),
      3000
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    //clearInterval(this.timerID);
  }

  tick() {
     console.log('called', this.props.no);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Clock {this.props.no}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  
  constructor(){
     super();
     this.state = {unMount: false}
  }
  
  click(){
     console.log('unmounted successfully');
     this.setState({unMount: !this.state.unMount})
  }
  
  render(){
    return (
       <div>
          <button onClick={() => this.click()}>Unmount first</button>
           {!this.state.unMount && <Clock no={1}/>}
           <Clock no={2}/>
       </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='root'/>
```

Here i am rendering two clock component and unmounting the first one onclick of button that is happening successfully and it's updating the DOM also, even after unmounting the first component timer is printing the props values properly by `console.log()`.

**I am not clearing the Timer** in `componentWillUmount`:

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    //clearInterval(this.timerID);
}
```

**My Doubt is:**

```
this.timerID = setInterval(
   () => this.tick(),
   3000
);

tick() {
   console.log('called', this.props.no);
}
```

I am passing a **class method as callback** in timer so once component has been unmounted how tick function exist, How this timer is resolving `this` keyword and the `tick` function after the component unmounted? How `this.props.no` is having the correct value? why it's not throwing the error:

> can't read tick of undefined or tick is not defined

How it is maintaining the references to these functions?

Help me what i am missing here, please provide any reference or example.

Comment: _..as per my understanding once component unmount its all properties/methods will not exist after that._ That's not quite correct. Technically React component is a JS class (function) and _mounting_ make connection between this class and respective DOM stuff. When component is unmounted only this connection is destroyed but the respective JS class and its props/methods are _**still exist**_.

Comment: @hindmost thanks, but if that code will still exist then it should create the memory issue since component get render and unmount very frequently when we visit different pages correct? another thing is, till what moment that code will be available because i waited for 10 mins but still that is printing the values properly, it should throw error after some time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unlike C++, you cannot explicitly delete objects from memory (aka 'destroy') in JavaScript. You can only delete references to them. Once no more references point to the object or its properties, it is eligible for garbage collection. Only then the garbage collector actually destroys it.

[Memory Management — JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management)

In this case, even after unmount you still have valid references to the object and its properties in your closures (`this.tick`, `this.props`, etc). At some point, after execution, they will go out of scope, then later your component will be destroyed and the memory will be released.

Answer (score 1):

Doing a lot of digging into the React code , I found the following **[doc](https://developmentarc.gitbooks.io/react-indepth/content/life_cycle/death_unmounting_indepth.html)**

and the code from the react github page

```
function unmountComponentFromNode(instance, container) {
  if (__DEV__) {
    ReactInstrumentation.debugTool.onBeginFlush();
  }
  ReactReconciler.unmountComponent(
    instance,
    false /* safely */,
    false /* skipLifecycle */,
  );
  if (__DEV__) {
    ReactInstrumentation.debugTool.onEndFlush();
  }

  if (container.nodeType === DOCUMENT_NODE) {
    container = container.documentElement;
  }

  // http://jsperf.com/emptying-a-node
  while (container.lastChild) {
    container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
  }
}
```

This suggest that  React will remove the Components from the UI and ready them for Garbage Collection, however even when the DOM elements have been removed the 
class instances are not so the methods, props still exist and hence setInterval continues to be executed.

Only when the references to `this.ticks()` and `this.props` are not longer used, they will be eligible for garbage collection

> JavaScript values are allocated when things (objects, strings, etc.)
>   are created and "automatically" freed when they are not used anymore.
>   The latter process is called garbage collection.

Comment: agree, but garbage collector will clear it after some time some x min, after that it should throw error, but that is not happening it's printing the values properly.

Comment: They will be, if they are no longer in use, but setInterval uses them and so they are not available for garbage collection

Answer (score 0):

This is outside the way `react` works and more just javascript. You should be clearing your interval on the `componentWillUnmount`. It even says in the docs:

> Perform any necessary cleanup in this method, such as invalidating
>   timers

Your code is commented out? Is that not the issue here?

```
  componentWillUnmount() {
    //clearInterval(this.timerID);
  }
```

Comment: that is my question, i am not clearing the timer and its printing the values, but how it is resolving the **this** keyword since i am passing a class method as the callback.

Comment: As it has a reference in memory, you passed the `lexical` `this`, which bound a copy of `this` when you did  `() =>`. I wouldn't be concerned so much with why it isn't doing that, when the documentation explicitly says you should do clean up there.

Comment: ya i also follow the doc, but just wanted to know the reason and why it is happening, thanks for you time :)